# Excel 2010 Margin Problems

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

My excel 2010 spreadsheet is in landscape orientation.  The right & left margins are set at 0.  However, the right margin is both showing & printing about 1" wide compared to about 1/4" on the left.  I must have some feature checked or unchecked that's causing this, yet I've tried changing things over and over without resolve. I even tried to manually move the right margin and it will not move.

Please help!!

Comment: This might be helpful in identifying the problem: [Excel file printing forcing margins](http://superuser.com/a/840162/364367).

Comment: I actually reviewed that before my post.  I don't think any of it applies.  I originally thought perhaps the printer margin etc but if that were the case, why would it effect the right and not the left? I of course checked  it anyways and the printer margins were all at 0, just like the layout margins.

Comment: More details will be needed for people to be able to help: printer model, OS, all of the relevant settings used, and an image of the printout.  There are too many possible problems to do more than speculate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet your far right column on that page simply won't fill the space in the right margin.  Just use the **Fit to page** option and let it work.  Printing the page won't necessarily force the column to stretch to the margin.  *And why would you want it to?*

[image]

Comment: I wish it were that simple. The columns are the exact width allowed by the page set up. If I adjust any column just by 1 larger size, it pops it over to a new page.  It's a large spreadsheet with a lot of data.  I would rather use that inch and allow some of the columns to be wider and/or have larger font.